# In Microsoft Excel how check if a calculated cell value is not in a list

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel, I need to check if the background color of a cell is not white. The GetFillColor() may return 2 or -4142 for white color.

I need something like this:

=IF(PERSONAL.XLSB!GetFillColor(A1) NOT IN (2;-4142) ...

I tried using OR, AND and curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using MATCH.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(PERSONAL.XLSB!GetFillColor(A1), {2,-4142}, 0)), "Not white", "White")
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks, Norie. The trick is that in Excel Portuguese version we need to switch comma by semi colon in the lists (besides the translated formula names).